# Setting cookies on subsequent request in Spring Security filter

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, cookies, spring-security

Our app uses 2 urls. One is **"example.com"** and another is **"my.example.com"**. The former is the public domain of our app, whereas the latter is intended to be used by logged in users only.

The problem seems to be with the following: when we're trying to send a request from just **"example.com"** to a part of our application that requires authentication we get 403.

Here's how it works:

1. A user sends a request to **"example.com"** (for example makes a rest call)
2. The request is caught in a spring security filter and the user is redirected to **"my.example.com"**
3. The cookies on the **"my.example.com"** are missing in the request headers, hence, we get 403

The code of a filter that redirects a user is as follows:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // fixing CORS
    if (httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        addCorsHeaders(httpServletResponse);
        return;
    }

    String contextPath = httpServletRequest.getContextPath();
    String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().substring(contextPath.length());
    String method = httpServletRequest.getMethod();
    ensureEvalSet(httpServletRequest);


    String currentHost = httpServletRequest.getHeader("host"); // "example.com"
    String myUrl = cutProtocolPart(getSessionAttribute(httpServletRequest, MY_URL)); // "my.example.com"

    // Lots of uninformative business logic, can be just simplified to
    // the following: "my.example.com" equals to "my.example.com"
    if (cabinetHostEqualsRequestHost(currentHost, myUrl)) {
        // we just filter down the chain...
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        //here we redirect the user from "example.com" to "my.example.com"
        String redirectUrl = getUrlToRedirect(myUrl, httpServletRequest); // "my.example.com"
        // additionally add CORS headers
        addCorsHeaders(httpServletResponse);

        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    }
}


private void addCorsHeaders(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    // was supposed to make cookies pass between "example.com" and "my.example.com"
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}
```

Here's how it's reproduced in Chrome:

Here's the request that redirects (from **"example.com"**, with auth cookies and headers)

[image]

And here's the second request to **"my.example.com"** with missing request cookies

[image]

Here are request headers of a request to **"example.com"** (with all the auth cookies)

[image]

And finally the request headers of a request to **"my.example.com"** (with the missing cookies that I want to be included from my request to **"example.com"**)

[image]

**My question is how to copy request cookies to the second request from the first one, so that user is authenticated?**

I tried to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` cookie but it didn't help

Comment: I guess it's because of the way you're setting the cookie. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain).

In your screenshot, could you also show the request headers?

Comment: @Procrastinator I've included request headers of both request, please take a look